# Resolving multiple Moq objects based on a condition using Autofac

Tags: unit-testing, c#-3.0, moq, autofac

Hi I am using Moq with Autofac while creating unit tests. I have scenario where my SUT mutiple instances of a type depending on the constructor parameter. i would like to Moq these instances.
I have an interface **ISpanRecord**:

```
interface ISpanRecord 
{
RecordType RecordType { get; }
string RecordId { get; set; }
string RecordText { get; set; }
ISpanRecord ParentRecord { get; set; }
List<ISpanRecord> Children { get; }
}
```

I have another interface **IRecordTypeFactory** which provides for a new **ISpanRecord** on the basis of **RecordType** (which is an enum)

```
interface IRecordTypeFactory
{
ISpanRecord GetNewSpanRecord(RecordType recordType);
}
```

The above interface is used by the SUT **SpanParser** class

```
internal class SpanParser : ISpanParser
{
// Private Vars
    private ISpanRecord _spanFile;
    private readonly IRecordTypeFactory _factory;
    private readonly ISpanFileReader _fileReader;

//Constructor
public SpanParser(ISpanFileReader fileReader)
    {
        _fileReader = fileReader;
        _spanFile = Container.Resolve<ISpanRecord>(TypedParameter.From(RecordType.CmeSpanFile),
                                                                TypedParameter.From((List<SpanRecordAttribute>)null));
        _factory = Container.Resolve<IRecordTypeFactory>(TypedParameter.From(_fileReader.PublisherConfiguration));
    }

// Method under test
public SpanRiskDataSetEntity ParseFile()
    {
        string currRecord = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            var treeLookUp = Container.Resolve<ITreeLookUp>(TypedParameter.From(_spanFile),
                                                            TypedParameter.From(_fileReader.PublisherConfiguration));

            IList<string> filterLines = _fileReader.SpanFileLines;

            ISpanRecord currentRecord;
            ISpanRecord previousRecord = _spanFile;
            List<string> spanRecords;

            foreach (var newRecord in filterLines)
            {
                currRecord = newRecord;

                //check if we got multiple type of records in a single line.

                spanRecords = _fileReader.PublisherConfiguration.GetMultipleRecordsText(newRecord);
                if (spanRecords == null)
                    continue;

                foreach (var recordText in spanRecords)
                {
                    RecordType recordType = _fileReader.PublisherConfiguration.GetRecordType(recordText);

                    currentRecord = _factory.GetNewSpanRecord(recordType);

                    // some more logic

                    GetPreviousRecord(ref previousRecord, currentRecord);
                }
            }
            // private method
            return GetSpanRiskDataSet();
        }

        catch (OperationCanceledException operationCanceledException)
        {
            // log
            throw;
        } 
    }
```

In the above class, while testing, i would like to get multiple objects of **ISpanRecord**  on the basis of RecordType.
Something like:

```
mockFactory.Setup(fc=> fc.GetNewSpanRecord(It.IsAny<RecordType>).Returns(// an ISpanRecord object on the basis of Recordtype)
```

As the above setup would be verified in a loop, so i would like to setup multiple cases. Please let me know what can be the solution or point me to the threads which do.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Returns` has multiple overloads, you're looking for those that take `Func<RecordType, ISpanRecord>` as argument. Having that sorted, you can build your custom return-logic:

```
mockFactory
    .Setup(fc => fc.GetNewSpanRecord(It.IsAny<RecordType>)
    .Returns((RecordType rt) =>
    {
         if (rt.Property == "value") return new DummySpanRecord();
         else if (rt.Property2 == "other value") return new FakeSpanRecord();
         else return new DefaultSpanRecord();
    });
```

Is there any reason you're using [**service locator** instead of **abstract factory**](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/RefactoringFromServiceLocatorToAbstractFactory.aspx)? If your container wasn't embedded in your SUT, perhaps tests would be easier (say, you wouldn't have to keep track of container itself and dependencies registering process).

Comment: On the contrary Service Locator has made it much easier for as i sometimes just add instances (mock instances) of dependencies and update the container which override the default classes in the container.
Can i achieve the same without using the service locator? Any links or how to's would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Darsin: usually, you don't use container in unit tests at all. Container should wire dependencies for you during application *runtime*, but in tests you do that explicitly so that *whatever's-going-on* remains transparent. Problem with service locator is that it [hides important stuff](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorIsAnAntiPattern.aspx) - will you remember that `SpanParser` requires 3 more dependencies than what it would seem from constructor signature, say 2 months from now?

Comment: Interesting article. I have been on the receiving end Autofac before. I guess i would have to relook its usage. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

In your setup, don't use `It.IsAny<RecordType>` - use specific values:

```
mockFactory.Setup(fc=> fc.GetNewSpanRecord(RecordType.Type1)).Returns(// an ISpanRecord object on the basis of Recordtype.Type1)
mockFactory.Setup(fc=> fc.GetNewSpanRecord(RecordType.Type2)).Returns(// an ISpanRecord object on the basis of Recordtype.Type2)
```

Edit: this assumes the simple case where `RecordType` is an enum (or other value type). If it's a reference type, you will need to use a more complicated technique like jimmy's.